# How to reuse RNN in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to implement a model like DSSM (Deep Semantic Similarity Model).

I want to train one RNN model and use this model to get three hidden vector for three different inputs, and use these hidden vector to compute loss function.

I try to code in a variable scope with reuse=None like:

```
gru_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(size)
gru_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(gru_cell,output_keep_prob=0.5)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([gru_cell] * 2, state_is_tuple=True)

embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [vocab_size, wordvec_size])
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self._input_data)
inputs = tf.nn.dropout(inputs, 0.5)
with tf.variable_scope("rnn"):
    _, self._states_2 = rnn_states_2[config.num_layers-1] = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, sequence_length=self.lengths, dtype=tf.float32)
    self._states_1 = rnn_states_1[config.num_layers-1]
with tf.variable_scope("rnn", reuse=True):
    _, rnn_states_2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,inputs,sequence_length=self.lengths,dtype=tf.float32)
    self._states_2 = rnn_states_2[config.num_layers-1]
```

I use the same inputs and reuse the RNN model, but when I print 'self_states_1' and 'self_states_2', these two vectors are different.

I use `with tf.variable_scope("rnn", reuse=True):` to compute 'rnn_states_2' because I want to use the same RNN model like 'rnn_states_1'.

But why I get different hidden vectors with the same inputs and the same model?

Where did i go wrong?

Thanks for your answering.

Update:
I find the reason may be the 'tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper' , when I remove the drop out wrapper, the hidden vectors are same, when I add the drop out wrapper, these vector become different.

So, the new question is :

How to fix the part of vector which be 'dropped out'  ? By setting the 'seed' parameter ?

When training a DSSM, should I fix the drop out action ?

Answer (score 1):

If you structure your code to use [`tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/DropoutWrapper), you can set `variational_recurrent=True` in your wrapper, which causes the same dropout mask to be used at all steps, i.e. the dropout mask will be constant. Is that what you want?

Setting the `seed` parameter in `tf.nn.dropout` will just make sure that you get the same sequence of dropout masks every time you run with that seed. That does not mean the dropout mask will be *constant*, just that you'll always see the same dropout mask at a particular iteration. The mask will be different for every iteration.